# I would like to wait for input on a browser and click in a box when receiving a specified request

Tags: imacros

I am a complete beginner in programming, and need to know where to start. I would like to be able to automate form filling on websites, like waiting for input in one part of the screen and then filling in my own data in another, or clicking yes in a specified box.
I have seen the program imacros, but cannot see how to get started

Comment: You may want to consider working through some basic tutorials first. http://wiki.imacros.net/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

First, Check out the iMacros wiki.  This will be your main source of information, and can answer most of your questions moving forward.
http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page

The form filling sample code will be helpful as well for this specific task.
http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-FillForm

If you download iMacros for Firefox, simply use the record function in the plugin and record yourself filling out the form, then modify with pieces from the form filling demo shown above.